# Prepare Ubuntu 16.04 server for template

Tags: 16.04, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, clone

I am trying to setup an Ubuntu 16.04.2 VM for my lab. I want to configure one copy of Ubuntu with generic settings and then clone the disk to make installation quick.

I know there is unique information in each Ubuntu install that needs to be removed in order to make each new clone a true unique VM. But I don't know what all needs to be removed.

Could someone please assist me in what files need to be removed so I can make a generic clone?

My target platform for the template is KVM-QEMU. So I am not actually going to be using templates like I would in VMware. At least not at this moment.

I am correct that files to need to be removed right?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking after installation from iso file and installation of `OpenSSH` server, you can install `cloud-init`.

The cloud-init script starts on instance boot and will search for a metadata provider to fetch a public key from. The public key will be placed in the default user account for the image.

Install the cloud-init package:

```
 sudo apt-get install cloud-init
```

When building Ubuntu images `cloud-init` must be explicitly configured for the metadata source in use. To set the metadata source to be used by the image run the `dpkg-reconfigure` command against the `cloud-init` package.

```
dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init
```

You can change the name of the account used by `cloud-init` by editing the `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` ...

This will you enbable to `ssh` to your instance created from template.

Only that you must delete is `MAC address details`

The operating system records the `MAC address` of the virtual Ethernet card in locations such as `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` during the installation process. However, each time the image boots up, the virtual Ethernet card will have a different `MAC address`, so this information must be deleted from the configuration file. Or you can simple delete `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Your image is ready to be template.

EDIT 1

Also you can consider to download image from [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release/)